# Scroll Bar bottom arrow not visible

Tags: css, html

i have a div tag which displays a scroll bar when it is populated but the problem i am facing is i am not able to view the bottom arrow of the scroll bar it goes below my footer how do i adjust it to appear above the footer my css is something like this

```
html {
        height:100%;
     }

body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
     }

div#content-wrapper {
                        voice-family: "\"}\""; 
                        voice-family:inherit;
                        margin-top:102px;   
                        margin-left:127px;
                        margin-bottom: 30px;
                        height: 100%;
                        overflow: auto;
                    }

body>div#content-wrapper {
                            margin-left:127px;
                         }
div#content {
                margin:0 auto;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
```

and the content is loaded in the following div

```
     <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
        </div>  
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your div's are overlapping it means that your document structure is not setup correctly or you have a flaw in your styling (css). If you did that on purpose you might want to look at the z-index property of css.

Comment: adjusting height: 100%; in content wrapper to certain pixels solves the problem in normal mode but when it is strecthed to full screen mode it shows grey space